# Adding DDR2 1066MHz to DDR2 800MHz memory

Tags: memory, graphics-card, motherboard, hardware-rec, ddr2

My Current system has 2x1GB DDR2 800MHz memory, installed on Intel DG965WH board which supports up to 1066MHz.

I would like to add some memory and my question is what would be the best configuration for me:

1. 2x1GB 800MHz + 2x2GB 800MHz = **6GB 800MHz**
2. 2x2GB 1066MHz = **4GB 1066MHz**

I also intend to by a video card (Sapphire ATI Radeon HD 6950 2GB GDDR5) which supports 1066MHz.

I use my computer for Java development and Games from time to time.

So what would give me the best performance? Quality or Quantity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nearly always quantity, assuming a basic level of quality, as long as you maintain dual- or triple-channel functionality.

"Quality" (speed) takes over once you've reached an amount of physical RAM that is no longer being completely consumed by the applications you're running.

Comment: Quality is a silly word though which the OP used to describe RAM speed. 6GB is so much RAM, that maybe less like 4GB, but more MHz may be more beneficial?  Also with your second paragraph, if the majority of the time 4GB isn't consumed, then I suppose it'd follow that he'd be best off with 4GB of faster RAM. Though if frequently 4GB is consumed, then I suppose he might want the 6GB slower RAM.

Comment: If he's purchasing a 2gb 6950, his gaming will certainly use more than the 4gb. Quality *is* a silly word, but not in the context of the question as asked.